# Getting error Uncaught Error: Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, google-visualization

I am trying to draw chart but getting this error "Uncaught Error: Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array." Tried lot of things but nothing worked.

Here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetChartData()
    {
        List<SubmittedSurveys> sResult = new List<SubmittedSurveys>();

        using (SurveyDBContext dc=new SurveyDBContext())
        {
            sResult = dc.SubmittedSurveys.ToList();
        }
        var chartData = new object[sResult.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]
        {
       "SurveyID","StartedDateTime"
        };
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var i in sResult)
        {
            j++;
            chartData[j] = new object[] { i.SurveyID, i.StartedDateTime.ToString() };
        }
        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my view of this controller

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>
    Column Charts for Submitted Surveys
   </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


  <script>

    var chartData;
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Reports")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                chartData = data.d;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data!");
            }
        }).done(function () {
            //after complete loading data
            drawChart();
        });
    });
    function drawChart() {
        
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
      
        var Options = {
            title: "Survey",
            pointSize: 5


        };

        var columnChart = new 
     google.visualization.columnChart(document.getElementById('DailyStatisticss'));

        columnChart.draw(data, Options);
    }

    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
   <div id="DailyStatisticss"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Please help me where I am doing something wrong. I tried to parse the ChartData like Json.Parse(chartData). but didn't work. Not sure where i am doing wrong

Comment: Put this after datatype and befor success. See if there is anything in the console window that will lead you to the cause.  error: function (_, err) {
                    console.log(_, err)
                },  Also put this in the success - console.log(response);
                    var jsonresult = response

Comment: data is most likely an object (`{}`) and not an array (`[]`)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to add as an array. I tried error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                } but getting same error and response is getting undefined.

Comment: Data is not coming back correctly. I am seeing what the issue is. It is something in the controller action. Json.

Comment: Can you please let me know exactly if i need to chNge something in controller

Comment: Working on  it...

Answer (score 0):

I have the data coming back as an array now. However you will have to try this and let me know if it is returning what you want. I am not using the same version of javascript as you.

For the JavaScript this is what I have

```
var chartData;
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Reports")',
            type: "Get",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var dataVis = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

        var Options = {
            title: "Survey",
            pointSize: 5


        };

        var Chart = new google.visualization.columnChart(document.getElementById('DailyStatisticss'));

        Chart.draw(dataVis, Options);
    }
```

You can put this in your `$(document).ready(function () {});`

For the array it is pretty simple but not sure if it was what you were after..

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var survey = from s in db.SubmittedSurveys
                     select new { surveyId = s.SurveyID, startedDateTime = s.StartedDateTime.ToString() };

    return Json(survey.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You would change `db` to whatever you use for your context or make one like this
`YourEntity db = new YourEntity();` and put it above `var survey`

Comment: I think, now that I have looked at this a bit more, Your issue is the data that you are pulling vs the chart you are trying to use. It is unclear what you are trying to populate. If you want # of in a year than you should be counting and grouping so that all in 2014 would populate one column for that year. Doing an array of records is not going to give you that.. IMO.

Comment: Your problem is the date.. You need to bring it back as just the year. The code you have will work but you need to fix the date column.